# Using wdTable() from R2wd Package: Table in Word is written but disappears automatically again

Tags: r, ms-word

This opens a Word document, inserts the plot (which stays in the opened Word file as it is supposed to) and quickly writes in the table as well (but then cancels the table in Word again):

```
require(R2wd)
require(RDCOMClient)
require(cars)

tab <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)))
# tab <- as.table(rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)))

p <- function(){
  plot(cars$speed, cars$dist)
}

wdGet()
wdPlot(plotfun = p)

wdTable(tab)
```

I can see the table is written in Word (very quickly), but right after writing it into the document it disappears. Have tried as `data.frame` as well as `table` format but both won't stay in the opened Word document.

How can I get such a `table` (and/or `data.frame`) into Word with `R2wd`?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Word Version: 14.0.6129.5000 (32-Bit) / Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010

Error Message:
 80020009 No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo checkErrorInfo -2147352567 Error : Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten. NULL Warning message: In wdTable(tab) : Error in table construction, removing

Comment: Please add your word version and error messages directly to your question (comments are less permanent than questions on SO).

Comment: `@Richard Erickson`: done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem on the function wdTable on the line

wdsel$InsertCaption("Table", caption, "", ifelse(caption.pos == "above", 0, 1), 0)

I've removed it, and it works.

In fact, what happened is that it does not recognize the "Table" word. If you change it to "Tableau" (in my case, since my computer understand French and not English...). 
So, finally it depends on the language defined of your document...